# Comparing getline() to string

Tags: c++

I am trying to read lines from a file one by one into an array using getline() and then compare the line to a string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ACCOUNT; i++)
{
  getline(accountFile, accountNum[i]);
}

for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ACCOUNT; i++)
{
    if (accountNumber == accountNum[i])
    {
        cout << "Account Number: " << accountNum[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

The comparison isn't working and the if statement isn't triggering even though when I print both `accountNumber` and `accountNum[i]` they are the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there a Carriage Return or Line Feed in the data?

Comment: Printing strings isn't good enough to confirm that they're the same. There are plenty of invisible characters.

Comment: Have you ensured that `accountFile` is open?

Comment: did you open the file in binary mode?

Comment: Jake, yes account file is open. Stephan, I'm not sure what binary mode is. I opened the file with `accountFile.open("accounts.dat");`

Comment: What is `accountNumber` declared as and how is it assigned a value?  Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Binary mode reads the data raw without any translations.  Some platforms translate CR/LF into LF.  There are other common translations too.

Comment: Are these `std::string` or `char*`?

Comment: Please post more code.